# FFMPEG GIF with transparency from png image sequence

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I've been trying to use ffmpeg to create a gif with a transparent background, but whenever the movement goes on top of the background, the pixels stay there. It's a tree with a wind animation, this is how it ends up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N036N.png

I first try to create the palette, and then the gif:

```
ffmpeg -i Tree_%04d.png -vf palettegen=reserve_transparent=1 palette.png

ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i Tree_%04d.png -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse=alpha_threshold=128 treegif.gif
```

It seems the previous frames simply stay there, but I can't figure out how to dispose of them.

Comment: Open [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6813).

Comment: Have you been able to figure anything out here because it still does not appear to work with ffmpeg 4.2.x

Comment: @LiamMartens I ended up working with webm files as those seem to work properly with transparency, I haven't revisited gifs yet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 21):

In the ffmpeg source code (libavcodec/gif.c) there are some command line flags - these are "-gifflags -offsetting", "-gifflags -transdiff" and "-gifimage".
I tried these on some sample frames with transparency, and I think the first of these produces the effect you describe:

```
ffmpeg -i Tree_%04d.png -vf palettegen=reserve_transparent=1 palette.png
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i Tree_%04d.png -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse=alpha_threshold=128 -gifflags -offsetting treegif.gif
```